# Div to show and stay on mouse hover - Stays up even when mouseout

Tags: javascript, css, hover, mouseout

I've been playing around with several ways of hover divs, but most of the methods I tested only stay up when the mouse is hovering over the link.

What I want to achieve is for the div to appear on hover of another div, but stays up even when the mouse leaves the div button.

An example would be: http://www.prixtel.com/

I don't mind if it's just CSS or mixed with Jquery/JS.

Thank you!

My sample: http://jsfiddle.net/h4rB9/1/

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event that makes the div visible (turning off display: none or whatever) to the mouseover event using something like the jQuery [.mouseover() bind](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).  If you don't specify a .mouseout() bind then it won't go away.

Answer (score 0):

That website is using script for that effect.

If you want to use JavaScript:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
if (document.addEventListener) {
  myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    // whatever it is you're doing on mouseover here
  }, false);
} else if (document.attachEvent) {
  myDiv.attachEvent("onmouseenter", function () {
    // whatever it is you're doing on mouseover here
  });
} else {
  myDiv.onmouseover = function () {
    // whatever it is you're doing on mouseover here
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
// I prefer mouseenter to mouseover, and jQuery lets you do that as does IE with attachEvent

$("#myDiv").mouseenter(function () {
  // whatever it is you're doing on mouseover here
});
```

As the other poster noted, the key is to omit the mouseout event - using hover automatically includes the mouseout behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I'm a complete novice with Javascript/JQuery, would you be able to elaborate what I will need to input?

Comment: The first part you need to decide is whether you want to use straight JavaScript or a library like jQuery. Then it's a matter of adding the appropriate script tags to your html, putting the script inside the appropriate ready/onload handlers. Which parts, specifically, do you need more elaborated on?

Comment: I'm unaware of how I can intergrate this with HTML/CSS, or what codes to use to merge with the divs. Example: <hoverdiv> opens <maindiv> when the user hovers over <hoverdiv>, and <maindiv> stays open until the user navigates to <hoverdiv2> etc.

Comment: Edit your original post and add the markup you're referring to or make a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate.